# How can I keep the drawn lines instead deleting them?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform startMarker, endMarker;
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    private float speed = 2f;
    private float startTime = 0f;
    private float journeyLength = 1f;
    private int currentStartPoint = 0;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    public void StartInit()
    {
        currentStartPoint = 0;
        SetPoints();
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.2f;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.2f;
    }
    void SetPoints()
    {
        startMarker = waypoints[currentStartPoint].transform;
        endMarker = waypoints[currentStartPoint + 1].transform;
        startTime = Time.time;
        journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startMarker.position, endMarker.position);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (waypoints.Length > 0)
        {
            float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
            float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
            Vector3 startPosition = startMarker.position;
            Vector3 endPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fracJourney);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, startPosition);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, endPosition);
            if (fracJourney >= 1f)
            {
                if (currentStartPoint + 2 < waypoints.Length)
                {
                    currentStartPoint++;
                    SetPoints();
                }
                else
                {
                    //if finished, disable lineRenderer and this script
                    lineRenderer.enabled = false;
                    this.enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each time it's drawing a line between two waypoints but then the line is deleted and then it's drawing a new line between the next two waypoints.

Instead I want it to draw one line between all the waypoints. And to keep the line in the end not to delete it.